# Varnish add more slash in URL

Tags: varnish

My varnish cache is accelerator mode and it cause adding more slash after URL.
I check with gtmetrix:

```
Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs.
https://www.example2.com/
https://www.example2.com//
https://www.example2.com/
```

and with google pagespeed test:
Reduce server response time
In our test, your server responded in 1.6 seconds. There are many factors that can slow down your server response time.

Here is my config:

vcl 4.0;

```
backend default {
.host = "localhost";
.port = "8080";
}

acl purger {
"localhost";
"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
}

sub vcl_recv {

 if (client.ip != "127.0.0.1" && req.http.host ~ "XXX.com") {
 set req.http.x-redir = "https://www.example.com/" + req.url;
 return(synth(850, ""));
 }

 if (client.ip != "127.0.0.1" && req.http.host ~ "YYY.com") {
 set req.http.x-redir = "https://www.example2.com/" + req.url;
 return(synth(850, ""));
 }
 if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purger) {
    return(synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
  }
 return (purge);
 }

 if (req.restarts == 0) {
 if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
 set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
 }
 }

 if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
 return (pass);
 }

 if (req.url ~ "/feed") {
 return (pass);
 }

 set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-\d+=[^;]+(; )?", "");
 set req.http.cookie = regsuball(req.http.cookie, "wp-settings-time-\d+=[^;]+(; )?", "");

 if (req.http.cookie == "") {
 unset req.http.cookie;
 }
}

sub vcl_synth {
 if (resp.status == 850) {
 set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
 set resp.status = 302;
 return (deliver);
 }
}

sub vcl_purge {
set req.method = "GET";
 set req.http.X-Purger = "Purged";
 return (restart);
 }

sub vcl_backend_response {
 set beresp.ttl = 24h;
 set beresp.grace = 1h;

}

sub vcl_deliver {
 if (req.http.X-Purger) {
 set resp.http.X-Purger = req.http.X-Purger;
}
}
```

Somebody know the reason why varnish do that ?

Answer (score 0):

`req.url` always includes a `/`  at the beginning.

so correct would be:

`set req.http.x-redir = "https://www.example2.com" + req.url;`

your question does not correspond to the example1/example2 as it includes XXX and YYY

if you can post a less redacted VCL - i may can help you a bit more
you may need a `!= "/"`  on `req.url` before redirecting. as this would result in a `//`